# Python lxml парсинг

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, lxml

Использую данный код для преобразования ответа с сервера в HTML-структуру

```
import lxml.html
request = request.get("https://....")
html = lxml.html.fromstring(request)
print(html)
```

При выводе print(html), выдаст результат наподобие вот этого `<Element html at 0x2a2b7989458>`

А как можно сделать, чтобы при выводе print выводилась именно структура Html найденого элемента, как в Beautiful Soup

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод `tostring`:

```
# Байтовый массив
print(lxml.html.tostring(root))

# Строка
print(lxml.html.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))
```

Чтобы вывести с отступами, то указывайте `pretty_print=True`:

```
print(lxml.html.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: root, это уже найденный элемент с помощью команды? html = lxml.html.fromstring(request)

Comment: Вместо `root` вставьте `html`